# Hermeneutics...?

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches

How old is the word hermeneutics?  How do I convey the fact that I keep the first in terms of greatest Commandments and for that reason your eyes have not seen ears have not heard nor has it entered into your heart my reality. May I have 4 or more explanations as to how I could convey my reality and your hearts actually believe the truth?

Comment: Welcome to BH. It may seem paradoxical but 'topics', as such, are off-topic on this site as hermeneutics concentrates on the text of scripture, not on general topics. If  you can reformulate your question to centre on a particular verse or word of scripture it may well be accepted.

Comment: If this is a question about the word "hermeneutics," it should be asked on a site about English or language. If it is about how this site is run (as your last sentence seems to hint), you can read the [help center](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/) or post on [meta](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Are you saying that your eyes/ears are open - that you have met Truth, and you want to know how to show others the path to Truth? There's a big difference in Knowing, for oneself, Truth - and 'believing'. Are you saying you want to know how to get others to *believe* that you Know Truth? I Agree that this is off-topic for this site, but I'd still like to understand your query.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's probably of-topic it is interesting question. Wikipedia answer it like that: The term was introduced c. 360 BCE by Aristotle in his text Perì Hermeneías (On Interpretation). 
Read more:
https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/hermeneutics